# Target class [User] does not exist. - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am learning laravel. I tried many times but I didn't find what's the issue in my User controller.Please go through the code and help me out.

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class
> [User] does not exist.

web.php file

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
                
                
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
    //return redirect('sample');
});

// Route::get('sample/{id}',function($id){
//     echo $id;
//     return view('sample');
// });

// Route::view('sample','sample');
// Route::redirect('youtube','sample');

Route::get('users','User@index');
Route::get('show','User@show');
```

This is my controller

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    class User extends Controller
    {
        //
        function index()
        {
            return ['name' => 'Abhishek'];
        }
        function show()
        {
            echo "Hello controller";
        }
    }
```

Comment: which laravel version you are using?? laravel 8?? in that case you have you use the full namespace to call a class in route file.

Comment: Its 8.9 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

laravel 8 route has been changed

you should declare route as such

you have 3 prefer for it ...

- 1

```
Route::get('user','App\Http\Controllers\User@index');
```

- 2

```
use App\Http\Controllers\User;


Route::get('user',[User::class,'index']);
```

- 3

if you don't want to change the route, look at the RouteServiceProvider and change ,
change `$this->namespace=null;`  as `$this->namespace='App\\Http\\Controllers';`
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

```
$this->namespace=null; //laravel 8

protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers'; //previous laravel version
```

[relevate line](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L29)

Comment: Yes, I am doing routing according to the laravel 7

Comment: Still, you get an error, probably wrong namespace or directory is wrong,  there here is no other explanation for this

Answer (score -1):

You need User model. If you created already, make sure your UserController has

```
use App\Models\User;
```

at the top. BTW, as I've noticed, your controller's name is User. This is bad practice. Following Laravrel's naming convention is not a must, but it can save you from a lot of headaches. User should be model name, UserController should be controller's name.